# Js scrollIntoView cannot scroll element to exact top of scrolling view

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use Vue as my project's framework.

js:

```
let captureElement = document.getElementById('tag' + (index - 1));
if (captureElement) {
    captureElement.parentNode.scrollIntoView({behavior:"smooth",block: "start", inline: "nearest"});
}
```

html:

```
<div v-for="(item,index) in data">
    <p class="tag" :id="`tag${index}`">{{item.catagory}}</p>
    <swipeout v-for="(item2,index2) in item.list" :key="`item${index2}`">
         //some code
    </swipeout>
</div>
```

> **how code produce:**

captureElement is `p.tag`
captureElement.parentNode is outside `div`
scrollIntoView's options are `{behavior:"smooth",block: "start", inline: "nearest"}`

> **what I expect:**

I hope `p.tag` will be scrolled into view at the exact top of it.

> **what actually happen:**

When I scroll to `p.tag#tag2`
There is a tiny gap above `p.tag#tag2` which is part of `p.tag#tag1`,probably its height is 1px.
see the screenshoot at below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> The element may not be scrolled completely to the top or bottom
>   depending on the layout of other elements.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Notes)

maybe that's a dead end...